# Can Silverlight access a .Net library that accesses a USB port?

Tags: silverlight, usb

We have a .Net library that accesses some custom hardware via a USB port.  I've read that Silverlight contains a subset of the .Net runtime.  So, my question is, would this subset be sufficient for the .Net library to function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES YOU COULD

an update only for people like me that founds this question, here the answer:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2011/09/27/pinvoke-in-silverlight5-and-net-framework.aspx

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot use a .NET library that accesses a USB port from inside Silverlight.

The closest you can get is an SL4 Out-of-browser app with elevated privs which can use COM components.