# Proprietary USB device access via browser... possible? Silverlight maybe? (Java is excluded for now)

Tags: silverlight, browser, usb, device

Probably there are a lot of similar questions around, but since I know only few solutions to this which I am not sure will work for us, I am looking for something else, maybe new technologies...

What we have is this USB device which is not so fancy (of course, it requires a driver to be loaded), and it has couple of C++ dlls to help getting certain output from it. On top, we made  a C# desktop application which makes use of the device in a more attractive way (plenty of interop inside).

So far so good, but to have the application lifted up to the web in order to gain more flexibility... What options are there?

Known solutions are:

- 1) **ActiveX** - kinda old technology and not cross-browser;
- 2) **.Net 'applet'** - not so common (is this even a solution?)
- 3) **Java applet** - well known, but JVM needed (since we went for C++ C#
  maybe    is out of scope);
- 4) **Web service on the usb device itself** - our    device is very
  light, we cannot have it there.

Are there other ways? Is Silverlight 4, 5 (maybe "out of browser") a feasable solution? What about these new technologies nowadays? **Html 5** or something?

**EDIT1:** In particular I am interested in Silverlight. Is there a way using **Silverlight**?

**EDIT2:** I found this question: [Can Silverlight access a .Net library that accesses a USB port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252683/can-silverlight-access-a-net-library-that-accesses-a-usb-port) . What shall I understand from that? Is really Silverlight not a feasable solution for my scenario?

**EDIT 3: VERY IMPORTANT!**

### These devices need to be used on customer side! People browsing must use them locally on their PCs!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems wrong to use a web interface, just because everyone else does. Why can you not mount (an additional) mass storage interface, which can host native client(s) for the supported operating system(s)?

Comment: As said, device is very light, we don't want to change the device. In plus, our application supports another type of device which is not ours, and this device doesn't have web services to access it. We could not change that either :)

Comment: So, you're saying you have a device, it needs drivers, but you don't want to put them on the device. So why not distribute your native client alongside on a CD? As I said before, It seems wrong to shoehorn this into a web app "just because", especially, as you'd need the prerequisites to make that happen. What is so wrong about using native apps, when the customer already needs to install drivers?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding somewhere. I never said i don't want to put drivers on it. Just I don't want to put any web server there. Do I get wrong your previous question?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: I changed my question so that you will be satisfied :)

Comment: My first comment was suggesting putting a native app alongside the drivers, rather than having a web app, as you've not demonstrated why it should be a web app

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: We have a big solution with server side on the web already, is a big management software. We would like to have the client side (involving the usage of device) migrated to the web as well, so that our customers will need only the browser when using our system. For them everything will be transparent if is server/client...

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: Probably the 'EDIT3 related thing' was causing the misunderstanding. Sorry for that.

Comment: Actually, I think that only confuses matters more - What do you mean by client side in this context? It sounds like you're connecting a device to a host via USB; The device needs some drivers to be usable, which you're including on the device, and you also want to build an application that exposes the data from the device in a user friendly manner, and you're insisting that's a web interface (so you're going to be needing to include a web server in your driver package)

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: Ok, I try one last time. Currently: Simple desktop app. Customers plug in the devices via USB on the local PC and use the app (this app is sending the data to a server, that is why the term 'client'). Future: Web app. Customers will still plug in the devices via USB on their local PCs, but they will use the browser to access the web app. Question was: what technologies could be used to achieve the latter?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: Again, there are multiple devices, for each PC where the customer would open the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> to have the application lifted up to the web [...]

Simple solution: Let the webserver (http server) run on the PC connected to the USB device, and use one of the webserver's interfaces like CGI to talk to your USB device. This way you  need to code only a USB-to-CGI wrapper program, which can be C++ or C#.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... Yeah, I agree with you, BUT these USB devices need to be used on client side, which means, the people browsing, need to use these devices :) ... I guess is an important point which I forgot to mention in my question

Comment: What I wanted to point out is that there should be multiple usb devices, connected to each PC which has a browser installed, so that the specific customer uses it (physically).

Comment: Actually I want to thank you for this idea... we would go for a solution which will use a nt service embedding the usb communication which will host some web services so that from the web application will create a redirection to 'localhost:{port}' to these web services from the 'client side' there were people are browsing...

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to write a browser plugin.

The issue that you're going to face is that content in a browser is often run in a sandbox, in such a way that the web app does not have access to the computer. There are good reasons for this - security, primarily. One way to have some code running in the context of the computer is to have a browser plugin that can access the computer's hardware resources, but that can interact with browser content. Unfortunately, you may end up writing a different plugin for different browsers.

There do exist frameworks out there that make writing browser plugins more manageable. A simple search should turn up some of those candidates.

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks for that... I will try to dig more into it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Silverlight 5, it can give you access to your file system and USB storage device. If you want to get control for other USB device (printer, scanner, etc), you should give a device type. I know, Silverlight 5 works fine with a file system and web-cams...)

Comment: The thing is that we don't have a file system there, it has only a 'FPGA' where we get raw data from. Will that still work?