# Server listen to Client Serial Ports

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, windows-services

I manage a web site for company that hired me after being unsatisfied with the original developer of the site.  One function of this site is to add new patients.  Part of adding the patient is to receive data from a USB port on the client machine via an applet.  Since the Java 7 update 21 the applet does not work and the company has asked to remove the applet and replace it with a different solution.  I am having trouble doing this, however, due to the applet listening to the client USB ports from the server to retrieve the data.  I Have thought of a few ideas to solve this but am unsure if it is possible and haven't been able to find the answer online.  I was hoping someone here could tell me if my idea is possible or point me in the right direction.

When the user adds a new patient the web site will call a web service on the server.  This web service will then call a WCF hosted Windows Service on the client and active its serial port listener.  Once the client's Windows Service has received the data the WCF will respond to the Web Service on the server and parse the data.

What I'm having trouble with is finding a way that the web service can call the WCF downloaded by the client and have it begin listening to the USB ports.  If anyone could tell me how to do this, or suggest a better way to have the server initiate the client listening to the serial port I would appreciate it.

Comment: The applet wasn't running on the server. It was running on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any system requirements?
When entering new patient, what kind of browsers are expected?
Will this be deployed as one solution, or clients expect that your application
can support any modern browser?

The main problem is that browsers are very restrictive in terms of what
kind of code you are allowed to execute. By default, browser won't allow
to execute any plugins / read any usb ports, let alone execution / installation 
of arbitrary wcf service.

So, supposing that you have 'any modern browser' in requirements - you have following options:

1. Java / activex applet plugin. I believe this is the only sure-way to have access to usb
   on a client machine. Also plugin must be signed with trusted certificate, or client must allow
   execution of untrusted plugin (again, check requirements). I though silverlight would also
   be a valid alternative, but according to my research (please correct if I am wrong) - its security
   model does not allow any kind of USB access.
2. Prompt user to download and install browser plugin / helper object with access to usb. 
   And then communicate with your web page through this plugin.

Installing an entire wcf service on a client side would be an overkill in my opinion.
You would have to manage issues like firewalls, closed ports, security, 
writing a self-hosting wcf solution, etc.

But if you managed to install and host a wcf service on a client side:

> When the user adds a new patient the web site will call a web service on the server. 
>   This web service will then call a WCF hosted Windows Service on the client and active its serial port listener.

Why not save a roundtrip and call client service directly from page?
Server would need to know client address to call it, which is not always possible.
Probably your web page can attempt to access localhost, at predefined port,
where your wcf service is listening.

> Once the client's Windows Service has received the data the WCF 
>   will respond to the Web Service on the server and parse the data.

It would be easier to respond on call from your web page (use polling if usb reading is slow), 
and only then send to server. Browser already knows where to send data, and have permission 
to do so. But if your server address is well known and can be accessed with domain name, 
you can try to connect to it from your wcf on client.

Also there is a very similar topic, discussing [connection to usb from client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705892/proprietary-usb-device-access-via-browser-possible-silverlight-maybe-java).