# How to fetch Finger Print using javascript(client side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to access my usb biometric device, is there any way to fetch finger print from client side using javascript. my device is (U.are.U 4500).

Comment: Read the data on the server, send it to the client via websockets.

Comment: i am not reading it from server, the problem is to read finger prints from client side and send it back to server.

Comment: Then you need to run a server on the client. The browser will not be able to access a low level USB device.

Comment: is there any other way to access using html5 and javascript, as we can access camera and mic using html5 javascript ?

Comment: A fingerprint reader is a very specific device. There is no generic API to access it. You will have to run extra software on the machine having the reader. It cannot be done in the browser only.

Comment: any other way to connect it with our web application ?

Comment: this might help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705892/proprietary-usb-device-access-via-browser-possible-silverlight-maybe-java

Comment: hi have you find a solution for that?

Comment: @rkaartikeyan, yes java applets can help.

Comment: @QasimKhokhar, do you've any link or reference on how you implement it.

Comment: I am looking forward to it.

Answer (score 5):

You can't access a USB peripheral directly through javascript or HTML as it is not included in any standard API. If there is a signed java applet available for it which exposes certain events and methods you could interface the javascript with the java applet to achieve some level of interaction but there is no way to achieve it through a strictly javascript/html manner.